# kafka http sink connector: request latency

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a http sink connector running in kubernetes. Its making requests to a rest service. The amount of messages consumed and sent to the topic seems low. Is there any metric which the connector publishes which gives the request latency?

Does anyone have any experience improving the throughput of an http sink connector? Any sugestions ?

we have tried increasing pod counts to match partition counts.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect is not unique to HTTP, and therefore won't have any built-in metrics for specific sink connectors.

That being said, the sink connector you use is a custom plugin to the framework, and may or may not have JMX metrics added, so therefore you'd need to setup something like `jmxterm`, VisualVM, etc to inspect if it does.

> experience improving the throughput of an http sink connector

You can configure any consumer client config. For example, `consumer.override.max.poll.records: 5000` will 10x the number of records that each poll will process before polling again. This also means that if any of those records fail, it may skip or redeliver them, based on the error tolerance settings

You can configure other settings like buffer sizes too. Check the Kafka docs for all consumer configs.

Comment: Thanks we will look at changing the poll records